# if we injects only primitive values of the same class through XML file then can we say we did the dependency injection in spring?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I referred some documents according to the spring in dependency injection.In some of them I found that if we insert primitive values of the same class using XML file then it is dependency injection.Is it right or wrong?
Or if we insert other class dependency(we insert reference of other class) through XML file is the dependency injection.Or both are right?

```
Student.java

package simple;

public class Student {


private int studentId;
private int studentAge;

public int getStudentId() {
    return studentId;
}
public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
}

public int getStudentAge() {
    return studentAge;
}
public void setStudentAge(int studentAge) {
    this.studentAge = studentAge;
}

}
```

Beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">



<bean class="simple.Student" id="student">      
    <property name="studentId" value="1" />
    <property name="studentAge" value="20" />
</bean>
```

Is this dependency injection or not?

Comment: It's hard to understand you question, can you elaborate, provide some sample code? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I agree, the question may be valid but it is hard to understand what you ask. Please clarify and add samples.

Comment: referred some documents? can you point to one of them

Comment: here is the link,http://www.java4s.com/spring/dependency-injection-with-spring-framework/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a naïve example, but you may claim this is a dependency injection.

> A dependency is an object that can be used (a service). An injection
>   is the passing of a dependency to a dependent object (a client) that
>   would use it. The service is made part of the client's state.[1]
>   Passing the service to the client, rather than allowing a client to
>   build or find the service, is the fundamental requirement of the
>   pattern. [wikipedia]

So your injector in this case the Spring framework via the xml bean definition provide the student id and age.

From my point of view your example will not help you better understand the dependency injection concept.

**Let me explain:**
As far as I like to understand dependency injection should be used mostly to create **Services** (usually singletons and not instance of prototype beans) the service dependencies can be inject externally.

Prototype creation via spring is not a common use case (I will omit the explanation for now).

A better example will be a **StudentDAO**  (DAO - Data Access Object) that will allow finding all Students or a Student by id. A **StudentFinder** that depends on **StudentDAO**.

Let’s assume you have two types of repositories used to store students file based and database.

So you will define an interface to your DAO.

```
public interface StudentDAO {
    List<Student> findAll();
    Student find(String studentId);
}
```

And two implementations:
 
File

```
public class StudentFileDAO implements StudentDAO {}
```

JDBC

```
public class StudentJdbcDAO implements StudentDAO {}
```

A finder that depends the DAO:

```
public class StudentFinder {
    private StudentDAO studentDAO;

    public void setStudentDAO(StudentDAO studentDAO) {
        this.studentDAO = studentDAO;
    }

    public List<Student> findAll() {
        return studentDAO.findAll();
    }

    public Student find(String studentId) {
        return studentDAO.find(studentId);
    }
}
```

Now when you want to define what type of DAO to use you will set Beans.xml as

```
<bean class="simple.StudentFinder" id="studentFinder">      
<property name=”studentDAO" ref="studentDAO"/> 
</bean>

<bean class="simple.StudentJdbcDAO" id="studentDAO ">      
<property name=”studentDAO" ref="studentDAO"/> 
</bean>
```

Or

```
<bean class="simple.StudentFinder" id="studentFinder">      
<property name=”studentDAO" ref="studentDAO"/> 
</bean>

<bean class="simple.StudentFileDAO" id="studentDAO ">      
<property name=”studentDAO" ref="studentDAO"/> 
</bean>
```

(Note that spring profiles will be better here, but let keep it this way so the example will be simple.)

Depending on the bean.xml you will provide with your system you define your system usage (jdbc/file). So going back to the definition from Wikipedia the client (studentFinder) does to build or find the service (DAO) it defined as  part of it’s state in the Beans.xml